# Python xml parser problems

Tags: python, xml, pandas

Simple code is not working and am looking for some help.

df has 44000 rows like this

```
<chat>
 <messages>
 <chat-message>
 <timestamp>2017-08-22T15:08:35.906-04:00</timestamp> 
  <name /> 
  <body>Hello Mikey, I see you want to chat with us today about: Account    
  Assistance. If you are chatting on a mobile device or tablet, your session 
  will end if you navigate away from the chat window. A representative will be 
  with you momentarily.</body> 
  <usertype>system</usertype> 
  </chat-message>
  <chat-message>
```

that are multiple  tags with their own  tags. I want to grab all the body blocks and merge into a single entry.

```
def msgg(row):
    root = ET.fromstring(row)
    work = ""
    for body in root.findall('messages/chat-message/body'):
        work = work + body.text
        return work


for row in df5['chat']:
    try:
       df5['test'] = df5['chat'].apply(msgg)

    except:
        pass
```

My function has a exception handler because without it I get this error:

```
    ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 32759
```

the internet said this error comes up when the xml file has bad tags. With the exception handler I get no errors but the code is taking forever to run; it's been running 35 minutes now; I'm certain when I finally get results they'll be garbage. Help!

Comment: How are you defining "ET"?  Are you using something like `from lxml import ElementTree as ET`?  Some find that to be faster than using other modules like `from elementtree import ElementTree as ET`.

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Comment: Do you get faster results with the lxml module in place of xml.etree?  Also, I don't know if perhaps an "xpath" search gives different results.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely problems with your tags. This means your dataset isn't clean and there are tags that are not closed properly such as

```
<name> stuff here <name />
```

It should instead be

```
<name> stuff here </name>
```

EDIT: I've created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844107/xml-tag-replacing-tag-with-tag) to help address the string replacement to fix this badly formed xml document. Hope this helps you solve your issue.

Comment: How to work around this? With the exception handling line in the code, it's taking forever to run

Comment: @M Sanders, you can write a script that reads all tags closed improperly `<name />` to `</name>`. It will involve `RegEx` patterns to identify `<name />`, then replace it with `</name>`

Comment: @MSanders I've created a question to help address your problem. You can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844107/xml-tag-replacing-tag-with-tag Hope this helps!